# Contour integration questions, help needed!

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate the following integrals, assuming all contours are orientated counter-clockwise
$$\int_{|z-1|=1}{\overline{z}dz}\\
\int_{|z|=2}(z+1)^2|dz|$$
${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You should be able to type the text of the problem as well as to demonstrate what you have tried to answer the question.

Comment: The following parametrization of the contours may be useful: for the first, $z=1+e^{i\vartheta}$, and for the second $z=2e^{i\vartheta}$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Concerning the first integral, it's done over the circle of center $1$ and radius $1$ ($|z-1| = 1$)

Hence the we can integrate over $[0,2\pi]$

By letting $\bar{z} = x-iy$, for $(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2$ and $dz = dx+idy$, the integral becomes:

$\int_0^{2\pi}\bar{z}dz = \int_0^{2\pi} (x - iy)(dx+idy) = \int_0^{2\pi} (xdx +ixdy - iydx +ydy) = \int_0^{2\pi} (xdx + ydy) +i\int_0^{2\pi} (xdy - ydx) $

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Hi thanks that has helped a lot. Still need to brush up on my understanding and practice more of these questions. Could you please kindly help by showing the result of the last integral you've typed out. And if you don't mind the second question as well because I'm trying to wrap my head around this circle stuff please.